# How to migrate from cgi to Fastcgi

Tags: fastcgi, overpass-api

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation#Setting_up_the_Web_API I have been using Overpass api(web api) using cgi, but i need to move to fastcgi to improve performance.hence i need to know how to alter my apache(2.4.18) httpd.conf file to use with fcgi module? P.S: Overpass api does not use php, rather we send the query to binary file, so in other words i need to know how to use fcgi module for binary files?

Comment: What did you try? What's your setup?

Comment: @Michael i am trying to run overpass api in my local server using cgi, but it creates a new instance for every request.so to prevent this i need to move to fcgi, i dont know how to change the conf file for this..
I have apache2.4.18 compiled from source with mod_proxy_fcgi.so module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/209 
This is the fastcgi version for Overpass-Api.

Comment: Careful, this is a prototype only, it has some known issues and is not supported in any way. Don't use it in production!

Comment: @mmd yeah,but when taking socket timeout's and response time into consideration this prototype seems good :) .